# JS cookie for displaying modal after X pageviews

Tags: jquery, javascript, cookies

I'm trying to use JS Cookie to display a login/register modal after in this case 4 page views, but its not firing and I'm not seeing any errors in the console. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here's the code with conditional added within head (I'll transfer this into a function once its working), and I'm using https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

```
<?php if(!is_user_logged_in() && is_singular('listings')) ?>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        // create cookie
        Cookies.set('visited', '0'); // visited = 0

        var VisitedSet = Cookies.get('visited');

        if(VisitedSet == 3) {
            jQuery("p.counter").html("From this point, you will always see the login/register modal on next visit!");
            jQuery(window).load(function() {
                jQuery('#overlay').addClass('open');
                jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},800);
                return false;
            });
        } else {
            VisitedSet++; // increase counter of visits
            jQuery("p.counter span").append(VisitedSet);
            // set new cookie value to match visits
            Cookies.set('visited', VisitedSet, {
                expires: 1 // expires after one day
            });

            console.log('Page Views: ' + VisitedSet);

            return false;
        }
    }); // ready
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

This is whats showing in the console NaN, although I'm setting the initial value of the cookie to 0

[image]

Here's the example I'm trying to pull from but updated to the latest version if JS Cookies http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/fancyboxOn4pageView_24jan12.html

Comment: `Cookies.set('visited')` should that possibly be `Cookies.get('visited')`?

Comment: That sets the initial cookie to 0

Comment: It does set it to 0 on every page view, though. There's no "is this cookie already there?", or is that contained in the js-cookie library?

Comment: Didn't even think of that, how would I add an "if exists"? Maybe if(VisitedSet != undefined) { // code here } else { Cookie.set('visited', '0') }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are set the cookie always to zero...

you need to check before if cookie exist value, only if the cookie not exist you will set the first cookie.

I fix your code here:
https://codepen.io/WebStorm-IL/pen/KZPVdY

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  // Get cookie
  var VisitedSet = Cookies.get('visited');


  if( ! VisitedSet ){
    // create cookie only if already not set
    Cookies.set('visited', '0'); // visited = 0
    VisitedSet = 0;
  }

  // increase counter of visits
  VisitedSet++;

  if(VisitedSet == 3) {
    jQuery("p.counter").html("From this point, you will always see the login/register modal on next visit!");
    jQuery(window).load(function() {
      jQuery('#overlay').addClass('open');
      jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},800);
      return false;
    });
  } else {
    jQuery("p.counter span").append(VisitedSet);
    // set new cookie value to match visits
    Cookies.set('visited', VisitedSet, {
      expires: 1 // expires after one day
    });

    console.log('Page Views: ' + VisitedSet);

    return false;
  }
}); // ready

(function( $ ){
  $("#resetCounter").click(function(){
    Cookies.set('visited', '0');
    location.reload();
  });
})( jQuery );
```

Comment: You're a rockstar! For some reason its not working when I replace the JS I currently have but works perfectly in the pen you created? I'm seeing "Page Views: NaN" in the console?

Comment: Let me see your full code. I think a link to your project will be either good.

Comment: Threw it up on a dev site real quick http://wordpress-96733-276335.cloudwaysapps.com/ — its kind of a mess but its all operational thanks again!

Comment: The script is only included on the single listings, like http://wordpress-96733-276335.cloudwaysapps.com/listings/escada-apartments/ or http://wordpress-96733-276335.cloudwaysapps.com/listings/8542-el-paseo-grande/ etc…I also changed the == 3 to == 4 page views.

Comment: Nevermind its working properly, something must be up with my local blocking cookies, thanks so much!